# Can't send SMTP email because of missing ptr records

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, server, smtp

I am using SMTP. There is nothing wrong with my code. The output is successfully send but I do not received email. When I check my mailbox in my server I got a message in my inbox which is saying that it is failed to send due to missing ptr records.

```
The IP address sending this message does not have a
550-5.7.1 PTR record setup. As a policy, Gmail does not accept messages from
550-5.7.1 IPs with missing PTR records. Please visit
550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more
550 5.7.1 information. dn3si12455081pac.266 - gsmtp

source code
function send_email()
{
     $config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
      $config['smtp_host']    = 'server.multimedia-street.com';
      $config['smtp_port']    = '465';
      $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
      $config['smtp_user']    = 'bjmpncr@thefourpobu.com';
      $config['smtp_pass']    = 'mypass';
      $config['charset']    = 'utf-8';
      $config['newline']    = "\r\n";
      $config['mailtype'] = 'text';
     $this->load->library('email', $config);
      $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");  
      $this->email->to('ruedastefano@gmail.com');
$this->email->from('bjmpncr@thefourpobu.com', 'SJCDRRMO');
$this->email->reply_to('ruedastefano@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('Password Reset');
$this->email->message('We have reset your request. Your new password:  Do not reply to this email.');
 if($this->email->send())
 {
    echo "success";
 }else{
     echo $this->email->print_debugger();

 }

}
```

Comment: Can you update your source code?

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn done I put my code

Comment: as the error suggests you need to setup a PTR record for the server your are sending the email from. https://www.cloudns.net/wiki/article/40/. Ask your hosting company to add one.